# Auth guard driver [api] is not defined. Tymon JWT, Angular 2 and Laravel 5.3

Tags: angular, jwt, laravel-5.3

I have configured Tymon JwT package version 1.0.0-alpha.3 as per documentation and configured guard in congif/auth. php

but i keep getting

Auth guard driver [api] is not defined.

when i login any ideas!!?

Comment: Did u got any answer to this? which user model you are using?